# Ember Controllers w/ Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am having a lot of issues with returning data from a controller/accessing data from the store and manipulating it. If anyone could take a look at my example here, I'm trying to compile a data container that pulls from 3 different stores (only using 2 in the example to keep it simple). This observationData will hold an array of observation objects each with participant_name and an array of measure values. Inside the {{each}} will be components for the observation and inside that a component for each measure. For now, I'm just trying to get the observations to display.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ewuXOhu/5/edit

I may be going about this the wrong way and would appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all:

I was missing return_value.pushObject(tmp_obj). I had return_value.push(tmp_obj).